# rewrite this code to use in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to rewrite the following code to use in .NET 2.0?

```
// Using dynamic (.Net 4.0 only)
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
string firstName = me.first_name;
string lastName = me.last_name;
string email = me.email;

// Using IDictionary<string, object> (.Net 3.5, .Net 4.0, WP7)
var client = new FacebookClient();
var me = (IDictionary<string,object>)client.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

Comment: write the code and after you see that it doesn't works, ask for help! this community is here to help, not to do your job

Comment: 1. Cut the first line into the .NET 2.0 project. 2. Compile. 3. Fix errors. 4. GoTo 1.

Comment: `IDictionary<,>` is fine in 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoulbn't be that hard to figure out but here:

```
//instead of var use the actual type
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
//again use the actual type
IDictionary<string, object> me = (IDictionary<string, object>)client.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"]; //May use 'me["first_name"].ToString()'
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

Answer (score -2):

The template classes can be replaced with their non-generic counterparts. Use `Object` type collections with casting. Assuming that's your compile issue.

Comment: Well I don't feel like guessing what doesn't work for him :P

Comment: "// Using dynamic (.Net 4.0 only)" is the main issue, I suspect; although to be fair, the second such comment (about dictionary) is incorrect

Comment: I guess that's a bad on my part. At least generics didn't exist at some point. (C# 1.1?)